# AES with PKCS#5 padding

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bouncycastle, jce

In quite a few places, I see Java code that uses AES with PKCS#5 padding. I do not understand how this could possible work.

PKCS#5 padding is meant to be used with ciphers that have a block size of <= 8 bytes. The block size for AES is 16 bytes. Is all the code that is out there that uses AES with PKCS#5 wrong? Or does the framework internally use PKCS#7 instead? The frameworks in question would be Sun provide in Java, JCE and BouncyCastle.

Comment: [Can AES use PKCS#5 padding](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/can-aes-use-pkcs5-padding)

Comment: PKCS#7 is used internally. Actually the two methods are technically identical, ignoring the size restriction for PKCS#5.

Comment: @Henry Could you add that in as an answer?(Preferably with some link to code that shows that PKCS#7 is used internally).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a programming problem but about a cryptography. Also, as already noted, it is already answered in http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/can-aes-use-pkcs5-padding

Comment: @OlegEstekhin The question is not about the use of cryptography. Its about the APIs that do it. I'm clear on which padding scheme is to be used and what the differences are-- not on what the API is, and what is used internally. Additionally I've requested a link to the code in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is indeed using PKCS#7 instead. The reason that `"PKCS5Padding"` is specified is very likely due to compatibility with the older DES and 3DES ciphers. Note that PKCS#5 padding is exactly 8 bytes, not less. Bouncy Castle usually follows the Sun/Oracle providers for the sake of compatibilty, although you can also use the more correct `"PKCS7Padding"` for the Bouncy Castle provider.

More information [on the crypto site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172) (disclaimer: pointing to my own popular Q/A).